# Does iPhone supports multicasting and broadcasting?

Tags: iphone, multicast, broadcast

Does iPhone supports multicasting and broadcasting?

iPhone is the client and i have server running desktop (Mac/Windows) machine.
Since the Windows does not mandatorily supports Bonjour, I ll have to follow some other steps.

Is there any other way of detecting the machines which runs the my server running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone supports Berkley sockets (and you can access it), so you can go with it to send broadcast/multicast messages, just have to write a bunch of code for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.We need to know the IP of machines (Both Mac and Windows) connected to the network first right? If yes how to get the IP of machines which are connected to the same network?

Comment: Basically, you can try sending out a broadcast message to discover which machines are on the same network. If the machines are running your own software – just make it respond to your broadcast, and you are done. In case you want to connect to some standard software (smb, afp, ...) – you'd better look for open source libraries, which shall do the discovery as well.